# How can I make this stopping criteria effective?

Tags: java, if-statement

I dont know why this stopping criteria keeps failing but I believe it has something to do with the logical or (||).  I debugged and it doesnt seem to stop where I want it to, which is on when cp (current position) is on the perimeter of the array.

```
 if(cp == start || (cp.getColumn() > 0 || cp.getColumn() < maze[0].length-1 || cp.getRow() > 0 || cp.getRow() < maze.length+1)){`
```

This is a for a maze solving algorithm.  Basically, the maze is a 2D array made up of X's for walls.  Every cell with an X is a wall and the 'current position' can not access it.  The mission of the 'current position' is to get to out of the maze which means it either has to be in the first or last column or first of last row.  The algorithm works very well but just doesn't recognize when the current position is at the index of the exit.

I'm sorry for being so vague, I've been working on this for so long...

Comment: What's this? Can you post more code or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, none of the following things is true:

- cp == start
- cp.getColumn() > 0
- cp.getColumn() < maze[0].length - 1
- cp.getRow() > 0
- cp.getRow() < maze.length + 1

But you think (at least) one of them should be true.  Which one?

Comment: The end point of the maze is at maze[1][8].  When the current position is that it should reject the recursion from continuing because cp.getColumn() is = maze[0].length-1 where length-1 is 8.

Comment: but you are asking whether column is LESS THAN 8, not whether it is EQUAL TO 8.  Maybe you want `<=`.  But it doesn't make sense; I would expect it to be less than the limit, until you are done (so I would expect that the test would return `true` immediately).  It's hard - maybe impossible - to figure out without more context.

Answer (score 0):

Being or statements, that extra set of parentheses are redundant:

```
if(cp == start || cp.getColumn() > 0 || cp.getColumn() < maze[0].length-1 || cp.getRow() > 0 || cp.getRow() < maze.length+1){
```

I can't see exactly what you are doing, but I hope this helps at least...

Answer (score 0):

I con't really see what you're trying to do here, but guessing that 'maze' is a two dimensional array, it should probably be `maze.length-1` in the last comparison. However, this would make the if statement evaluate to `true` when cp is NOT on the perimeter of the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you've copied your code correctly

```
 if(cp == start 
        || (cp.getColumn() > 0 || cp.getColumn() < maze[0].length-1 
        || cp.getRow() > 0 || cp.getRow() < maze.length+1)) {
```

For simplicity of understanding pretend that maze.length[0]-1 evaluates to, say 3, then consider this bit:

```
cp.getColumn() > 0 || cp.getColumn() < 3
```

That will be true for every value of the cp.getColumn(), try say 8, yep, bigger than 0, -99, yep it's less than 3. I'll bet you meant

```
cp.getColumn() > 0 && cp.getColumn() < 3
```

this will be true if the column is in the maze. If you want to test for out of the maze:

```
cp.getColumn() <= 0 || cp.getColumn() >= 3
```

(Side note I use <= 3, not just == 3 deliberately, this deals with cases such as move of more than one step.)

If you want to test if it's in the maze you have

```
 if(cp == start 
        || (
             cp.getColumn() > 0 && cp.getColumn() < columnCount 
             && cp.getRow() > 0 && cp.getRow() < rowCount)) {
```

if you want to test if it's outside the maze

```
 if(cp != start 
        && (
             cp.getColumn() <= 0 || cp.getColumn() >= columnCount 
             || cp.getRow() <= 0 || cp.getRow() >= rowCount)) {
```

Comment: I dont think were on the same page

Comment: I misunderstood your maze[] piece. But please read my final two suggestions again, I reckon they are giving you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are using the start conditions in your OR set.  You may want to put an ! (Not) before the first bracket.  As written, I think the else clause would be where your stop should occur.

Consider wrapping the processing code in this if statement.

Desk check your logic to see when you exit. Remember that OR stops processing on the first TRUE, and AND stop processing on the first FALSE.